# Override default "Only x left" message

Tags: magento2, stock-status

I want to extend default **"Only x left"** message. Can you tell me which file controls it?

At the moment message is visible only when **stock is less than qty threshold**. I want if stock is more than qty threshold, to show message "More than qty threshold" and if sock is 0 or below 0(I have activated backorder)  to show "Orderable with delivery" message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you asked 2 questions. To override the template file and override the block function.

The first one is easy.The original file is on `vendor/magento/module-catalog-inventory/view/frontend/templates/stockqty/default.phtml`. To override this file, you can copy this file and paste it on your active theme. So that `app/design/frontend/Your_Vendor/Your_Theme/Magento_CatalogInventory/templates/stockqty/default.phtml`. You can start editing it now.

The second one is a bit tricky, but still OK. To override the original threshold function `isMsgVisible`, you can just modify it a bit.

1. Create a new module. Let's say, **MyVendor_CatalogInventory**. Create a new file `app/code/MyVendor/CatalogInventory/etc/module.xml` and add the following content:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
       <module name="MyVendor_CatalogInventory" setup_version="0.0.1"/>
   </config>
   ```
2. Create new file `app/code/MyVendor/CatalogInventory/etc/di.xml` and add the following content:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
       <type name="\Magento\CatalogInventory\Block\Stockqty\AbstractStockqty">
           <plugin name="MyVendor_CatalogInventory::aroundIsMsgVisible" type="MyVendor\CatalogInventory\Block\Stockqty" sortOrder="10"/>
       </type>
   </config>
   ```
3. Create new file `app/code/MyVendor/CatalogInventory/Block/Stockqty.php` with the following content:

   ```
   <?php

   namespace MyVendor\CatalogInventory\Block\;

   class Stockqty{


       public function aroundIsMsgVisible()
       {
           //Start your logic here
       }
   }
   ```
4. Enable this module

   ```
   cd <your magento root>
   php bin/magento module:enable MyVendor_CatalogInventory
   ```

Ref: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/extension-dev-guide/plugins.html

Comment: Thanks mate. I didn't check it, but that should be the way.

Comment: Stockqty.php returns error "parse error: syntax error, unexpected ; expecting identifier t string on line 3

Comment: Something with namespace declaration, can you help with that

Comment: You can ask another question :)

Comment: Thanks a lot, it is really helpful

Answer (score 0):

Will it be possible modifying only default.phtml file to have:

If StockQty > 0 && StockQty < QtyThreshold --- StockQty pcs

If StockQty > QtyThreshold ---. More than QtyThreshold

If StockQty <=0 ---. With delivery: $stockdelivery (we will have such attribute with drop-down)

And show nothing if In Stock is set to Out of stock.